# John The Ripper - how to try all combinations from individual given expressions in a password list?

Tags: john-the-ripper

In order to understand what should be done in a real user case, I made this test:

- I created a GnuPG key, with the passphrase `twothree`
- I exported the private key part of it (ASCII armored)
- I generated the hash file for this part by using the gpg2john utility
- I creted a password.lst file (replacing the default one) with the expression `twothree` as its single line

Now:

- running john on the hash file using the --wordlist=password.lst option will find the password almost instantaneous
- running john on the hash file with no other option will find the password after a minute or so, at the stage when it comes to the password list method

However:

- if I split the password from the password.lst file into two lines, i.e.

```
    two  
    three
```

then john is no longer able to find the password [in reasonable amount of time], regardless if using the --wordlist option or not.

I suppose (?) this involves the rules somehow, but I am not able to proper configure the rules for this usage.

What I want is to instruct john to include all possible combinations of the words (expressions) from the given password.lst file, which in this test can be `two three twothree threetwo`.

For a real user case, I need to find a forgotten passphrase that is most likely (only) a combination of a few possible known expressions – not that many, but enough to be too complicated to try manually all of it.

What should be done in order to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was never able to figure out how to do this with John, but hashcat can do it very easily with a [combinator attack](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=combinator_attack).

From the [docs](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=hashcat), Hashcat GPG mode seems to be 17010. Copy the gpg2john hash to a separate file (ex. hashes.txt) and make sure it matches the [specified format](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes#:%7E:text=17010)

The attack itself is explained clearly at the link, but all you should need to do is run it with the same wordlist on each side:

```
./hashcat64.bin -m 17010 -a 1 hashes.txt wordlist.txt wordlist.txt
```

Could also [increase the workload profile](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=hashcat#:%7E:text=%2D%2Dworkload%2Dprofile) if you want for larger dicts.

Answer (score 0):

This is simply possible using hashcat, if you are flexible with the tool choice. You can check the documentation on https://miloserdov.org/?p=6032#8
under section "How to create combined dictionaries".

**Dictionary 1 (dict1.dict):**

```
two
```

**Dictionary 2 (dict2.dict):**

```
three
```

*Note: Ensure that there is end of line character in each dictionary after the last line.*

This is called a Combinator attack, its detailed description: https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=combinator_attack

**Launching a combinatorial attacks (-a 1):**

```
hashcat -a 1 --stdout dict1.dict dict2.dict > tmp12.dict
```

**Temp Dictionary 12 (tmp12.dict):**

```
twothree
```

**Launch again in reverse order:**

```
hashcat -a 1 --stdout dict2.dict dict1.dict > tmp21.dict
```

**Temp Dictionary 21 (tmp21.dict):**

```
threetwo
```

**Copying all 4 dictionaries together:**

```
copy dict1.dict + dict2.dict + tmp12.dict + tmp21.dict all.dict
```

**Content of all.dict:**

```
two
three
twothree
threetwo
```